# How to access the object returned by a function inside python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have the following python class:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):

   def onChanged(self, text):
   
     return text

   def buttonClicked(self):
   
     print(self.onChanged)
```

when I run the script i get the following result:

```
<bound method Example.onChanged of <__main__.Example object at 0x7fde1cab0550>>
```

My question is how to get the content of the text returned in  `onChanged` function ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `print(self.onChanged)` you don't call the function, you should execute `print(self.onChanged())` instead.